# Auth session in Cakephp is not deleted on close browser

Tags: authentication, cakephp, session-cookies

I want to delete the Auth session created in the site when user close the browser

I have seen and tested other solutions posted and releated to this, but none of them helped me.
This is my configuration in core.php:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
        'defaults' => 'php',
        'cookie' => 'MYCOOKIE',
        'timeout' => 10,
        'cookieTimeout' => 0,
        'checkAgent' => false,
        'autoRegenerate' => false,
        'ini' => array(
            'session.cookie_secure' => false,
            'session.cookie_lifetime' => 0,
            'session.gc_maxlifetime' => 600,
            'session.cache_expire' => 180,
            ),
    ));
```

Here the relevant settings in php ini:

```
session.cookie_lifetime=0
session.gc_probability=1
session.gc_divisor=1000
session.gc_maxlifetime=1440
session.cache_expire=180
```

I have a "Are you still there?" functionality to ask the user every 10 minutes about the session meanwhile the browser is open.

I have tried with `'cookieTimeout' => 0'` and `'session.cookie_lifetime' => 0'` settings but session is alive when reopen the browser.

I also tried to change the handler from php to cake, and many other combinations,

Is there any thing Im missing?

Using Cakephp 2.5

UPDATE

I was searching and seems to be that, browser like FF and Chrome have this "Open everything as it was before." setting. And this leave few solutions as the "Clear cookies and other site and plug-in data when I close my browser" in chrome or "Keep until you close Firefox." or simply not to save your tabs when reopen your browser.

This is not a great finding. I turned off those options and all my cookies are deleted as expected. But I cannot control every computer in the world =(.

However my session is deleted after 10 minutes as i had.

I'll try with other resources like SessionStorage but I fear it will be the same result. Maybe an ajax observant?

Thanks in advance.